# How to find whether last key pressed is the 'Return' key?

Tags: tkinter, indexing

A gesture keyboard app where the user drags cursor to create a word. The result of this get stored in the result[] list. The program needs to check whether the last key pressed was the 'Return' key.

How do I do this?

Some context- a separate python file (linked with the main file of course) creates the keyboard where the variable key_names stores the values of all keys on keyboard.

not sure??

```
if result[-1] == 'Return:    
    for i in range(len(result)):
        if i < len(self.label_word_candidates):
            self.label_word_candidates[i].config(text=result[i][1])
```

Comment: Are you aware that tkinter has *Keyboard-bindings* built in ? What do you do there to ask such a odd question ? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: You're missing single quote 'Return: should be 'Return':